# How to stub subcomponent EventEmitter from UI module

Tags: angular, jasmine, vmware-clarity

I have an Angular project where I use the Clarity Design UI framework.  My project uses Clarity's DataGrid component and listens to its [`clrDgRefresh`](https://v1.clarity.design/datagrid/server-driven) `EventEmitter` which triggers in response to changes in the underlying data or user interactions.  I'm writing tests for a component that involves changes that trigger this `EventEmitter` and I'm trying to figure out how to stub the callback on these events so that they are not triggered during testing.  How can I do this?

My component template contains

```html
<clr-datagrid (clrDgRefresh)="dgRefresh($event)">
```

where the `@Output` on Clarity's DataGrid component is

```js
@Output('clrDgRefresh') public refresh = new EventEmitter<ClrDatagridStateInterface<T>>(false);
```

and my component has something like

```js
@Debounce(400)
dgRefresh(event: any) {
  this.doSomething();
}
```

where I want to stub `doSomething` in tests (or just prevent it from being called).

My spec file has:

```js
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ClarityModule,
        ...
      ],
      ...
    })
    .compileComponents();
```

I can't just `spyOn(component, 'doSomething')` since it only stubs direct calls to the function and not those triggered asynchronously through Clarity.  I also can't do something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35319476/any-way-to-test-eventemitter-in-angular2) since I'm using the entire module and not just a single component.

I also tried to get the instance of the DataGrid component that is created within my component and stub that with

```js
let datagridDebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.datagrid'));
let datagrid = datagridDebugElement.componentInstance;
spyOn(datagrid, 'refresh');
```

But that also doesn't work (`doSomething` is still called).  What's the right way to approach this?

Comment: Can you `spyOn(myComponent, 'dgRefresh').and.doNothing());`? (or maybe `and.callFake(() => myFakeCallback());`

Comment: @TheHeadRush I run into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49396736/can-webpack-4-modules-be-configured-as-to-allow-jasmine-to-spy-on-their-members/54757283#54757283

Comment: Can you help me understand a bit more. It seems like the application needs to disable the `clrDgRefresh` @Output but only in a test. I'm unsure why an application would need to do this. Is there any way you can show a recreation or simplified version of your test? Stackblitz or github repo?

Comment: Our application allows cross-filtering between some plots and a datagrid that shows the underlying data.  We listen to `clrDgRefresh` to see when the user applies some new filters to the datagrid.  Once this happens we apply all the datagrid filters to the raw data to figure out what data is now accessible (a workaround to https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/253) and then update our plots using the filtered data.

Comment: The problem is that `clrDgRefresh` is emitted not only in response to user actions, but also by things like adding data to the table.  Our plotting process involves calling an API to do some fitting and we want to stub this in tests.  I actually have a demo repo that does something very similar to this -- I'll update it to the latest Clarity release and add it here.