# testing an emitted value in child component

Tags: angular

Update: answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35319780/7729975

Angular 8.

In my child component, I have:

```
   @Output() selectedProduct = new EventEmitter<Product>();

   handleProductSelection(product: Product){

    this.selectedProduct.emit(product);

    }
```

child.component.html:

```
<button *ngFor="let product of products" (click)="handleProductSelection(product)">{{product.productName}}</button>
```

I want to write a unit test that confirms that when called, handleProductSelection() will force selectedProduct to emit the product passed.

So far I have:

```
 it("selected product is emitted out", () => {
    const product = new Product(SampleProducts[0])
    component.handleProductSelection(product);
    component.selectedProduct.subscribe() // dont catch it

  });
```

Basicaly, after the method is invoked, I want to capture the emitted value to make sure the passed/clicked product is what is emitted to the parent.

Comment: Answered by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35319780/7729975

Comment: Thanks @christian that did it.