# Jasmine test constructor params

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have the following code

```
this.myEvent.emit(new MyModel({prop1: true, prop2: 'someString', someOtherProps...}))
```

In jasmine I have

```
const spy = spyOn(component.myEvent, 'emit');
```

How can I check that `myEvent` has emitted an object with property `prop1 = true`?

Comment: Don't spy on the thing you're supposed to be testing, see e.g. https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-inside-a-test-host

Comment: Hmm, how would I then check that the `component.myEvent.emit` has been called? `toHaveBeenCalledTimes` expects a spy not a function.

Comment: You wouldn't, because that's an implementation detail. Test the actual behaviour, which is that a parent component binding myEvent would receive the right value at the right time.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Okay, well then imagine I am in the parent component, and I want to test that the child has emitted an object with property `prop1 = true`? So the question stands.

Comment: @jonrsharpe please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35319780/8188883

Comment: Sadly lots of people do the wrong thing, because it seems easy and they don't know any better. Here's the right answer, from someone who's got a lot of Angular knowledge, in line with the guidance in the official docs I already shared: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35319537/3001761. And if in the test host you want to check that the `prop1` property of the emitted value is `true`, what is stopping you from `expect(emittedValue.prop1).toBe(true)`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe the issue I have is that prop1 is a constructor argument, so in a way I have to check that `MyModel` has been instantiated with  prop1 = true.

Comment: No, you don't. You have to test that the behaviour of the emitted value is consistent with that value having been true. If it's exposed as a prop that's obviously straightforward, if not then we can't tell you how to test that without seeing the implementation of MyModel. Otherwise you're testing that a test double of the emitter was called with a test double of the model that was called with an object, which is too coupled to current implementation.